# Should I use :after or ::after in JSFiddle?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, jsfiddle

In CSS3 (the latest CSS), should I be using ::after or :after?  JSFiddle says that I should use 2 colons instead. I am starting a club where I am teaching people HTML and CSS, so I want to make sure I'm teaching them the right thing because the message JSFiddle puts may confuse them. I also want to know this for myself.

Comment: JSFiddle's CSS linter is a bit strange. Auto-tidy gives one output, but then the linter tells you to change it, which will be reverted if you ever press Tidy again

Comment: IE 9+ supports `::after`, so it's safe to use *and* the modern way of doing things

Comment: @CertainPerformance What is auto-tidy? And also does this mean there is a way to make the error/suggestion message go away? Or should I just stick with ::after?

Comment: There's a button called "Tidy" up at the top, which auto-tidies code. It works well with HTML and *mostly* well with JS, but not so well with CSS - though in this case, `::after` *is* the right thing to use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `::after` syntax. If you check [the current specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/) you can read:

> The main differences between the selectors in CSS2 and those in Selectors are:
>
> ...
>
> new pseudo-elements, and introduction of the "::" convention for pseudo-elements<sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#changesFromCSS2)</sup>

And

> This :: notation is introduced by the current document in order to establish a discrimination between pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements. For compatibility with existing style sheets, user agents must also accept the previous one-colon notation for pseudo-elements introduced in CSS levels 1 and 2 (namely, :first-line, :first-letter, :before and :after). This compatibility is not allowed for the new pseudo-elements introduced in this specification. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#pseudo-elements)</sup>

You will also find the same information in the future specification of [Selectors Level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#pseudo-elements)

> Because CSS Level 1 and CSS Level 2 conflated pseudo-elements and pseudo-classes by sharing a single-colon syntax for both, user agents must also accept the previous one-colon notation for the Level 1 & 2 pseudo-elements (::before, ::after, ::first-line, and ::first-letter). This compatibility notation is not allowed any other pseudo-elements. **However, as this syntax is deprecated, authors should use the Level 3+ double-colon syntax for these pseudo-elements.**

Comment: I don't understand the specification link you sent, what is the section i should navigate to? Thank you for the answer though.

Comment: @Stocker added reference for each block